# ql golang database (ql/cznic)

Tags: database, go

The golang based sql database ql/cznic (see github) lists the major SQL keywords
but it will not responds "ORDER BY x ASC"  nor will it Support ranges in the WHERE Clause.

Is there a way to perform these operations or am beating a dead horse?

Comment: `ORDER BY x` should act like `ORDER BY x ASC`. For BETWEEN-like behavior, you could see whether querying `x >= a...ORDER BY x`, then iterating results and stopping iteration when `x >= b` is efficient, or whether `x >= a and x <= b` is efficient. Posting as a comment 'cause I don't personally use `ql`, and hoping someone who does can answer.

Comment: twotwotwo --- IT WORKED!  The correct command was:

Comment: "SELECT * FROM t WHERE i > 500000 ORDER BY i"  and it produced a ascending order list.  Let us hope I don't need to go the other way!!!

Comment: You should post it as an answer (preferably with more code) to help people in the future.

Comment: Unless your dataset is small and you just want the semantics, you should also check if it's *efficient* when you want, say, the first 50 items when there are thousands with `i > 500000`. I don't know how ql implements this; getting the first 50 results might look at only ~50 rows, or it might look at all of the rows with `i > 500000` regardless of how many or few you look at.